# What's the technology of bind MAC address with IP address, for solving iP conflict issue?

Tags: networking

What's the technology of bind MAC address with IP address?

I have a problem with the LAN, such as in my LAN, there are `192.168.100.0/24`, gateway is `192.168.100.254/24`.

user A's IP is `192.168.100.1/24`, the user B's IP is `192.168.100.2/24`.

now there is a problem, the user B config the `192.168.100.1/24`, so they can not use the network normally.

so I hear about there is a technology can avoid this issue, if the user B config the A's IP address, will not affect user A's normal usage.  but I don't know what's the technology. who can tell me about this?

Comment: do you have cisco device? what is dhcp server hardware modal? cisco router,switch....etc

Comment: @infra I mean a user can bind other user's IP for fun, or other bad idea on purpose.

Comment: you should remove user permission to add static ip address on their computer. And If you have dhcp server then you can bind ip address and machine mac address or you can add static ip address for user computer

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The usual approach is to set up a DHCP server that takes care of IP address distribution. If a node requires a permanent address you use a reservation.

When a DHCP server is used you can set up DHCP snooping with strict MAC/IP binding on the access switch - the switch monitors the DHCP lease and disallows any other IP address. Alternatively, you take away the user's privilege to configure the address locally.

If you tell us more about your network and the devices in your question we can probably help you set it up.

Comment: Generally, DHCP snooping isn't sufficient. You also need DAI/ip source guard enabled to protect from this issue.

Comment: @YLearn Yes, that's what I meant by *strict MAC/IP binding* - there's a lot of names for that and the OP wasn't refering to any specific hardware.

Answer (score 1):

General Name for bind mac address bind with IP address is `MAC Binding,` Sometimes `IP reservation` also same name for `MAC address binding`. When you bind mac Address with IP address that IP address calls as `Reserved IP` or `Excluded IP`.

Answer (score 0):

A technology just like that couldn't exist as concept of network is based in *a ip address unique for a networking device (NIC) unique*.